# PHP Associative array from get_object_vars does not work for integer keys

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object used for storing current quantities of a product at various sites. The Site ID is used to indicate where the stock is, and it is used as an object key to point to the quantity.

The product can have stock at site 0 and site 2, but not necessarily have anything at site 1, thus it does not have to be set.

I tried using PHP get_object_vars() function and got the associative array, but when trying to access the values using the array_keys() function, they did not yield any output. Running a test script below, I found that using integers for the objects did not work as expected.

```
<?php


$obj = new stdClass();
$a = 'a';
$b = 1;
$obj->$a = 3;
$obj->$b = 6;

$vars = get_object_vars($obj);
$keys = array_keys($vars);

var_dump($vars);
echo("<br>");
var_dump($keys);
echo("<br><br>");

var_dump($vars[$keys[0]]);
echo("<br>");
var_dump($vars[$keys[1]]);
echo("<br><br>");

$vars = array("a"=>3,1=>6);
$vars['1'] = 6;
$keys = array_keys($vars);

var_dump($vars);
echo("<br>");
var_dump($keys);
echo("<br><br>");

var_dump($vars[$keys[0]]);
echo("<br>");
var_dump($vars[$keys[1]]);



?>
```

The output I got was:

```
array(2) { ["a"]=> int(3) ["1"]=> int(6) }
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "1" }

int(3)
NULL

array(2) { ["a"]=> int(3) [1]=> int(6) }
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> int(1) }

int(3)
int(6)
```

Is it possible to access the object properties if they were saved as integers?

Comment: Whats your problem ? you want it to return for example 3 instead of (int) 3 ?

this code is working as it should, edit your question and add your intended output.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your code exactly as copy/pasted to a test script on my php7 server. I get `int(6)` instead of `NULL`. You could save yourself some headaches, and just ensure variable names are strings, so instead of just assigning `1`, assign `site1`.

Comment: If you want an associative array, just build one directly, no need for a stdClass object. Then you won't have to worry about what is allowed as a property name of an object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the PHP version that I ran my test scripts on was a bit outdated, tried my code on an up-to-date version and didn't return `NULL`. I guss this wasn't a bug or problem.